# jquery carousel with text and description

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery, jcarousel

i need to show content from my wordpress blog in a slider. i choose jcarousel as it can be loaded via ajax,

[Jcarousel link](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html)

This is rendered via an array with only image urls. i need to bring title and description of the image with ajax. i need a slider like this
[image]

how can i proceed.

```
$images = array(
'http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg',
'http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg',);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution using a WordPress plugin, [ajax-post-carousel](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-post-carousel/), need to customize, but works perfectly.